# Align text on top, right, bottom and left of image?

Tags: css, position

I'm trying to add text on all four sides of image but i cant get the right text to align properly. The right text is still on left side.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/y75L0ww9/

```
<span class="top">Text on top</span>
<span class="left">Text on left side</span>
<img src="http://www.uaa.alaska.edu/web/images/horizontal-large.jpg" />
<span class="right">Text on right side</span>
<span class="bottom">Text on bottom</span>

img {    
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0px none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.top, .bottom {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FF0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0px;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #F00;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add wrapper around Your image (for now it can be body), ad give it `position: relative;` Then modify .right class:

```
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #F00;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y75L0ww9/1/)

Comment: Thank you @Bogdan Kuštan for solving the problem!

Answer (score 0):

(*btw. in wider viewport the left text is also not so nicely layed out right now ;)* )

You will have to wrap all those 5 elements into another element, e.g.:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Having this, you'll be able to easily align your `span`s inside by giving them `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

use position: absolute; instead of position: relative;

[Updated fiddle](https://goo.gl/2BCz6i)